# How do i debug my cgi script with mysql database in python. I am new to how to debugg

Tags: python, debugging, cgi, mysql-python

My code is showing some error when runing on server. i checked the server error log and still not knowing what the exact it mean to say. It says premature end of script. 
Now I want to debug my code to check each and every line of code to what does it do ? How am i supose to debugg my code. I am really new to this.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import cgitb
import MySQLdb
import cgi

cgitb.enable()

form = cgi.FieldStorage()

f_name = form.getvalue('firstname', '')
l_name = form.getvalue('lastname', '')
age = form.getvalue('age', 0)
gender = form.getvalue('gender', '')

db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost", "root", "gaurav", "Info")

cursor = db.cursor()

sql =  "INSERT INTO PERSON (F_Name, L_Name, Age, Gender) VALUES ('%s',' %s',' %d',' %s')" % (f_name, l_name, age, gender)

try:
    cursor.execute(sql)
    #print "Hello !!"
    #print "no of rows inserted: %d " % cursor.rowcount
    db.commit()

except:
    db.rollback()

db.close()

print "Content-type:text/html"
print "<html>"
print "<h1>DATABASE</h1>"
print "</html>"
```

Comment: Why are you using CGI and not a web framework like Django, Tornado or Flask?

Comment: … or WSGI, which is specifically designed to be "CGI done Pythonically instead of 1990s-style".

Comment: Also, it is probably not a Good Idea to post your actual MySQL username and password on a public forum.

Comment: While we're at it, [never ever ever put user strings into your SQL statements like that](http://xkcd.com/327/). Instead, use parameterized statements: `sql = "INSERT INTO PERSON (F_Name, L_Name, Age, Gender) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)"`, then `cursor.execute(sql, (f_name, l_name, age, gender))`.

Comment: @frb: I can't think of a better way to prevent SQL injection attacks than to give people an even easier way to take over your database. :)

Comment: How do i debug now. I want to check waht each line does at what point. and print that into the file

Comment: @user2968229 There's no one way to debug. I usually debug by reading my script over five times and the Python documentation more times before realizing I forgot a single character.

Comment: When I read my code over 5 times I just become more and more convinced that I did everything right. When I take a break and come back an hour later, _that's_ when I see that I spelled `form` as `from` and emacs has been helpfully highlighting it for me the whole time and only an idiot could have missed it…

Comment: When i checked my code, it seems all fine to me. without cgi script and simply adding data to data goes fine, buit when done with cgi, it gives error

Comment: @user2968229: OK, so put back half the code you stripped out—for example, try the form stuff and the `print`s but not the database stuff in between. Keep adding or removing half the code until you narrow down exactly what bit makes the difference, and you'll eventually have just one statement to debug instead of a while script.

Comment: I tried only the form part and prints, it works fine. As soon as i write the import MySQLdb, it shows me the internal server error

Comment: @user2968229: OK, now we're getting somewhere. The logs should tell you what Python error caused that server error. It could be an `ImportError`, meaning that you just don't have `MySQLdb` installed on the server machine (or, if that machine has multiple Python installations, you don't have it installed for the Python that the server is using). Or it could be something different, or even a segfault, meaning something else is wrong.

Comment: If the logs don't tell you what happened, see the edited version of my answer for how to get the error information yourself.

Comment: I have mySQLdb installed and its working fine without cgi form

Comment: @user2968229: So you only get the error if you put in both the form stuff _and_ the SQL stuff?

Comment: Yes when only form is executed it working fine and when only database is executed its working fine. Problem occurs when both both the import comes together.It gives segmentation fault

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that in HTTP, the headers have to end with a blank line. So, instead of sending one header line and a 3-line body, you're sending four header lines, all but one of which are nonsense, and then exiting without ever finishing the headers.

So, the server complains that the script exited without finished writing the response.

Try this:

```
print "Content-type:text/html"
print
print "<html>"
print "<h1>DATABASE</h1>"
print "</html>"
```

---

If you want to log every line of code, as you said in the comments, there are two ways to do it.

The quick&dirty way is to just open a file and `write` into it. For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import cgitb
import MySQLdb
import cgi

with open('/tmp/logfile.log', 'wb') as logfile:

    logfile.write('About to enable cgitb\n')
    cgitb.enable()

    logfile.write('About to create FieldStorage\n')
    form = cgi.FieldStorage()

    logfile.write('About to get firstname\n')
    f_name = form.getvalue('firstname', '')
    logfile.write('Firstname is {}. About to get lastname\n'.format(firstname))
    l_name = form.getvalue('lastname', '')
    logfile.write('Lastname is {}. About to get age\n'.format(lastname))
    # and so on
```

A cleaner way is to use the [`logging`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html) module that comes with Python:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import cgitb
import MySQLdb
import cgi
import logging

logging.info('About to enable cgitb')
cgitb.enable()

logging.info('About to create FieldStorage')
form = cgi.FieldStorage()
```

This is simpler (no need to add `\n` onto the end, the logger can format strings for you so you don't have to do it manually with `.format` or `%`, etc.). And it's a lot more flexible (you can log different messages at different levels, you can configure where the logs go—e.g., send them to your [system log](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.handlers.html#logging.handlers.SysLogHandler) instead of a file in /tmp, etc.). And it's more robust (no need to worry about forgetting to `close` the file and losing the last log messages—note that in the non-`logging` example, I used a `with` statement to get the same effect, but that required indenting the whole program).

If you have time to work through the [Logging Tutorial](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html#logging-basic-tutorial), you should do so.

---

Finally, if you're pretty sure some line is raising an exception, but you can't find the exception information anywhere in the server logs, here's how to log the exception:

```
import traceback
try:
    the line that raises
except Exception:
    traceback.print_exc(None, logfile)
    raise
```

This captures the exception, prints out the exact same detailed traceback you would have gotten in a console interpreter session, but into the log file you opened earlier instead of to the console, then lets the exception propagate normally.

If you're using the `logging` module, you can use its own built-in exception logging, or if you want to customize things you can use `sys.exc_info` and `traceback.format_exception` to get a string (or series of strings) to log.

Comment: Now how do i debugg ?

Comment: @user2968229: The first thing to do is simplify your script—keep stripping things out until it either works, or no longer has anything to strip out. For example, if you remove all the form stuff and all the database stuff and just do the `print`s at the end, does it work? (One reason it might not is that some servers require you to end each line with `\r\n` rather than just `\n`.)

Comment: @user2968229. The second thing to do is to add logging into the script. For example, you can use the stdlib `logging` module, direct it to write to syslog or to a file (make sure it's one the web server's user has write access to!) or even to the database, and then add `logging.info` lines throughout your code to make sure it's running everything it should be.

Comment: removing all the database and form stuff prints the data on the web page. Someone told me to create a function in your code of debugging and check each and every line to what does it do and print that into some abc file

Comment: Now i am not getting to how do i do that ?

Comment: @user2968229: If you don't want to read up on the `logging` module as I suggested, you can instead wrap the whole script in something like `with open('/tmp/logfile.log', 'wb') as logfile:` and then use `logfile.write('About to create the sql string\n')`, `logfile.write('About to call execute\n')`, etc. (It's a little less work to get started than a real logger, but a lot less flexible and less simple to use.)

Comment: i am not getting that logging concept. could you plases show the snippe b'coz i am not getting in the comment

Comment: When i have form print on the web page it works fine.. Now as soon as i uncomment the imort mysqldb it shows me server error ? What could be the problem behind importing mysqldb ?????

Comment: Writing your code and executing says me Segmentation fault - logging module

Comment: @user2968229: If just importing a pure-Python module out of the standard library segfaults the process, there must be something seriously wrong with your Python installation. So that's what you need to fix. How did you install everything?

Comment: This segmentation fault never occured previously. When i tried today for cgi and mysql database, it says so

Answer (score 0):

By checking all the possibility of error i found a solution that sequence of import matters here

it should be like

```
import cgi
import MySQLdb
```

instead of

```
import MySQLdb
import cgi
```